# Google maps API showing fullscreen and zoom icons 3 times in each button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google maps API component in a component's Shadow DOM that has recently started displaying like this:

[image: broken map]

The fullscreen, zoom in `+` and zoom out `-` are each displayed 3 times in their respective buttons.

My init code looks something like this:

```
new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
    keyboardShortcuts: false, // MUST be off, thanks to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73644075 breaking all key inputs across Shadow DOM
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{ featureType: 'poi', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] }] // Hide POI so our markers are more obvious
});
```

However, if I enable `streetViewControl` or `mapTypeControl` they don't display three times, it's only the fullscreen and zoom controls.

Here is the issue extant (needs a browser that supports Shadow DOM): https://jsfiddle.net/KeithHenry/6yfmehLr/

Why are the additional images appearing?

How do I fix or work around this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more instructions on how to reproduce this?
I can't see a problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/k5aqmo3s/1/

Comment: @StephenFarrar I think the problem is due to the map being loaded in a web component, put a shadow DOM above it and you get the error: https://jsfiddle.net/KeithHenry/6yfmehLr/

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the Maps API https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122064478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a hack that works around this, for now.

Add the following styles to the shadow root:

```
.gm-control-active > img {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.gm-control-active > img:nth-child(1) {
    display:block;
}

.gm-control-active:hover > img:nth-child(1),
.gm-control-active:active > img:nth-child(1) {
    display:none;
}

.gm-control-active:hover > img:nth-child(2),
.gm-control-active:active > img:nth-child(3) {
    display:block;
}
```

These are added by the Maps API to the `<head>`, but these don't cascade through any Shadow DOM. This is a bug in the API: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122064478

As this is a bug in the API this question is resolved. Please star the linked issue if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just use :

```
#map img:not(:first-of-type){display: none}
```

(where `#map` is the id of the map container).

Prettier, and it looks to make everything clear.

Comment: It's less CSS, but you lose the hover and button active effects, and potentially hide other images in the control. The selected answer replaces the styles that the maps expects to have cascaded from the `document` (but that haven't because shadow DOM). This is just one of a load of fixes needed to get the Maps API working with modern browser tech (or even just shadow DOM) and I wrap all of those in a single map web component, so simpler CSS isn't as useful as a full (if horribly clunky) fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can also revert to an older version (3.35) to workaround for now.